# Embedding Youtube Videos in React Native Application

Tags: android, react-native, webview, youtube

I understand this is a highly documented issue and I have been trying to find a solution, but everything that I have found online so far has not worked. So I wanted to show what I have tried to do and what goes wrong:

I tried embedding Youtube videos within a WebView. The following method builds the application successfully, but when I click on the video, the application crashes. I understand this works with IOS, but I'm test building the application on an android emulator

```
<WebView
    style={ styles.video }
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    source={{uri: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/dFKhWe2bBkM' }}
/>
```

Another method I tried was this, but I get an error.

```
<WebView
    style={ styles.video }
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    source={{ html: "<html><body><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RJa4kG1N3d0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"  }}
/>


error: bundling failed: SyntaxError in C:\DIRECTORY\VideoPage.js: C:/DIRECTORY/VideoPage.js: Unexpected token, expected , (33:56)
31 |               style={ styles.video }
32 |               javaScriptEnabled={true}
> 33 |             source={{ html: "<html><body><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RJa4kG1N3d0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"  }}
 |                                                         ^
34 |             />
35 |
36 |           </View>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I haven't been able to get this problem fixated yet, but will post when I do. Using the react-native-youtube package did not work for me, but I will post my solutions in time

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube

```
import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube'

<YouTube
  videoId="KVZ-P-ZI6W4"   // The YouTube video ID
  play={true}             // control playback of video with true/false
  fullscreen={true}       // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
  loop={true}             // control whether the video should loop when ended

  onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
  onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
  onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
  onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}

  style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300 }}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: This might be good, but you have to `detach` your *expo* project from *expo* and sometimes you face number of unwanted and unexpected issues, which take a good amount of effort to resolve. This is the point where I see `react-native` limitations and difficulties.

Comment: this depend on Youtube App

Answer (score 0):

You must use ' ' in attributes of iframe tag as you are wrapping this html code in " "

like this :

```
<WebView
javaScriptEnabled={true}
source={{ html: "<html><body><iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/RJa4kG1N3d0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>" }}
/>
```